# Overriding an inherited property setter

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a class called `Node` that has an `importance` setter and getter, below:

```
class Node:

    @property
    def importance(self):
        return self._importance

    @importance.setter
    def importance(self, new_importance):
        if new_importance is not None:
            new_importance = check_type_and_clean(new_importance, int)
            assert new_importance >= 1 and new_importance <= 10
        self._importance = new_importance
```

Later on, I have a class `Theorem` that inherits from `Node`. The only difference between a `Theorem` and a `Node`, as far as `importance` is concerned, is that a `Theorem` must have an `importance` of at least `3`.

How can a Theorem **inherit** the `importance` setter, but add on the additional constraint that `importance >= 3`?

I tried to do it this way:

```
class Theorem(Node):

    @importance.setter
    def importance(self, new_importance):
        self.importance = new_importance # hoping this would use the super() setter
        assert self.importance >= 3
```

Comment: Note you could solve the problem completely differently by having a class attribute `MIN_IMPORTANCE` that is `1` in `Node` and `3` in `Theorem`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding properties in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019643/overriding-properties-in-python)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can refer to the existing property directly through the `Node` class, and use the property's `setter` method to create a new property from it:

```
class Theorem(Node):
    @Node.importance.setter
    def importance(self, new_importance):
        # You can change the order of these two lines:
        assert new_importance >= 3
        Node.importance.fset(self, new_importance)
```

This will create a new property into `Theorem` class that uses the getter method from `Node.importance` but replaces the setter method with a different one.
That's how properties in general work: calling a property's `setter` returns a new property with a custom setter, which usually just replaces the old property.

You can learn more about how properties work by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/2505645) (and the question too).

Comment: `TypeError: setter() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. Did you mean `fset`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ups, try now :P

Comment: Yep, much better, and neater than mine!

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen So writing `@Node.importance.setter` above the definition of `importance` is the same thing as writing `importance = Node.importance.setter(importance)` below the definition of importance?

Comment: @mareoraft indeed that's how *all* decorators work, the `@` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I often saw the convention that property getters have names such as `get_importance` and setters have names such as `set_important`, and I follow this convention. However, when I test your code, it **only** works if the setter method in the child class `Theorem(Node)` has the same name as the property. In other words, if I replace `def importance(...)` with `def set_importance(...)` in your code, then it stops working (it doesn't override the parent class's property setter). This seems a bit counterintuitive. Is it a bug or not?

Comment: @Marses It's definitely intended behavior, you can read more about properties here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 5):

Here is a completely different solution to the broader problem, with a lot less faffing around:

```
class Node:

    MIN_IMPORTANCE = 1
    MAX_IMPORTANCE = 10

    @property
    def importance(self):
        return self._importance

    @importance.setter
    def importance(self, new_importance):
        if new_importance is not None:
            new_importance = check_type_and_clean(new_importance, int)
            assert (new_importance >= self.MIN_IMPORTANCE and 
                    new_importance <= self.MAX_IMPORTANCE)
        self._importance = new_importance


class Theorem(Node):

    MIN_IMPORTANCE = 3

    # and that's all it takes!
```

To my mind, this expresses:

> The only difference between a `Theorem` and a `Node`, as far as `importance`
>   is concerned, is that a `Theorem` must have an `importance` of at least `3`.

a lot more clearly than overriding the property setter does.

---

Note that `assert` is generally used for testing and debugging, rather than as part of the general program flow, and certainly not for things that you expect *could* happen; see e.g. [Best practice for Python Assert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944592/3001761).

Comment: This is the best solution for the *specific example problem* posed.  The accepted answer above is the accepted answer because it addresses the question asked and is on-topic with the title.  Nevertheless, I appreciate this well thought out answer.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is by implementing a new property on `Theorem` using the `Node` getter, providing a new setter method and calling the `Node` setter explicitly within it:

```
class Theorem(Node):

    def _set_importance(self, new):
        Node.importance.fset(self, new)
        assert self.importance >= 3

    importance = property(Node.importance.fget, _set_importance)
```

As far as I'm aware, this cannot be done with `super`.

---

Per [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue14965), you could do:

```
class Theorem(Node):

    def _set_importance(self, new):
        super(Theorem, Theorem).importance.fset(self, new)
        assert self.importance >= 3

    importance = property(Node.importance.fget, _set_importance)
```

However, this is clearly a bit awkward; the patch to allow `super()` instead appears to be scheduled for Python 3.5 (due in [September 2015](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/)).

Comment: Don't pass `self.__class__` to `super()`.  It will totally break when you subclass from `Theorem`.

Comment: @Kevin will it? A quick test indicates it getting up to `Node.importance.fset` from a `Theorem` subclass instance.

Comment: ISTM that `super(TheoremSubclass, TheoremSubclass).importance` will return the object you created on the last line.  That should produce infinite recursion once you call `fset()`.

Comment: @Kevin you seem to be right, and I can't figure out why that didn't happen first time!