# Access superclass' property setter in subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, overriding

I have a SuperClass which defines a property and it's setter, like so:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mode = None

    @property
    def mode(self):
        # to be overriden in subclass to implement the actual getter code
        raise NotImplementedError

    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        # common assertions and input validations
        self._set_mode(value)

    def _set_mode(self, value):
        # to be overriden in subclass to implement the actual setter code
        raise NotImplementedError


class B(A):
    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode

    def _set_mode(self, value):
        self._mode = value


obj = B()
obj.mode = 'test'
```

Which raises

```
obj.mode = 'test'
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

It would seem that I have to register a setter in B. I'd usually do this like `@A.mode.setter`, but that doesn't quite apply here as I don't actually want to define a new setter in B, just re-use the one from A.
Does anyone have a hint on how to solve this? Might be trivial, but I'm not seeing it right now :/

Comment: I just occured to me that I could add an explicit getter method like so and have the mode property call this getter `return self._mode_getter(), with _mode_getter() then being overriden. this should work, but adds a method which may not be required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the getter and setter are stored as attributes of the `property` object (respectively as `.fget` and `.fset`), so as soon as you overload the property in a child class you most explicitely provide both getter and setters, ie:

```
class B(A):
    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode

    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        self._mode = value
```

So if you want to make the getter and/or setter overloadable without having to redeclare the property, you have to define a `_get_mode` method and make your property's getter delegate to this method, just like you did for the setter.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mode = None

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._get_mode()

    def _get_mode(self):
        # to be overriden in subclass to implement the actual getter code
        raise NotImplementedError

    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        # common assertions and input validations
        self._set_mode(value)

    def _set_mode(self, value):
        # to be overriden in subclass to implement the actual setter code
        raise NotImplementedError


class B(A):

    def _get_mode(self):
        return self._mode

    def _set_mode(self, value):
        self._mode = value
```

Answer (score 3):

Analogously with using `mode.setter` inside `A`’s definition, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909212/3071700) to a related question suggests to use a property of a base class to define a property on a subclass like so:

```py
class B(A):
    @A.mode.getter              # only this line is changed!
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode

    def _set_mode(self, value):
        self._mode = value
```

Here, `mode.setter` will be the same as it was for `A`, but we’ve replaced the getter.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me this way

```
class A:
    @property
    def mode(self):
        raise NotImplemented
    
    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        raise NotImplemented

class B(A):
    @A.mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        # your setter implement here
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to the [cpython bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/59170) is to fetch the setter from the parent class manually

```py
ParentClass.some_property.fset(self, value)
```

Example:

```py
>>> class A:
...     @property
...     def mode(self):
...         return 2
...     
...     @mode.setter
...     def mode(self, value):
...         print("A", value)
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     @property
...     def mode(self):
...         return super().mode + 1
...     
...     @mode.setter
...     def mode(self, value):
...         print("B", value)
...         A.mode.fset(self, value + 1)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> print(f"{a.mode = }")
a.mode = 2
>>> print(f"{b.mode = }")
b.mode = 3
>>> a.mode = 5
A 5
>>> b.mode = 5
B 5
A 6
```

If you want it parent-agnostic, then look through `self.__class__.__bases__`.