# Python property setter how to do multistage setting?

Tags: python

I have created two class A and B (use `@property` to get and set their attribute). class B has a member whose type is class A. How to set the attribute of `b.a.x`?

class A:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value
```

class B:

```py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, A):
            self._a = deepcopy(value)
        elif isinstance(value, tuple):
            self._a = A(value[0], value[1])
        elif isinstance(value, int):
            # ?           
            pass
```

```
b = B()
b.a.x = 1 # How to implementate this ?
```

Am I wrong with the using of `@property`?

Comment: What you have is a perfectly fine way to do it.

Comment: Did you try `b.a.x = 1`?

Comment: you may find useful information in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763283/access-superclass-property-setter-in-subclass

Comment: @rsiemens What confuses me is that `@a.setter` do not know to call `self._a.x=value` or `self._a.y=value` when an `int` value come in. Should I add `__setitem__` in both class?

Comment: `b.a.x = 1` calls the getter for `B.a`; this returns an instance of `A`, so the setter for `A.x` is then called.  No setter on `B` is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding print() to your classes shows the behaviour, calling `b.a.x = 1` will make x.setter in A class in charge not a.setter in B class

example:

```
class A(object)
    .
    .
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print('x.setter acting')
        self._x = value


class B(object):
    .
    .
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        print('a.setter acting')  # adding print 
        if isinstance(value, A):
            self._a = deepcopy(value)
        elif isinstance(value, tuple):
            self._a = A(value[0], value[1])
        elif isinstance(value, int):
            # ?           
            pass

b = B()
b.a.x = 1 # x.setter will be in charge not a.setter
```

output:

```
x.setter acting
```

if you want a.setter to be in charge you can:

```
class B(object):
        .
        .
        @a.setter
        def a(self, value):
            print('a.setter acting')  # adding print 
            if isinstance(value, A):
                self._a = deepcopy(value)
            elif isinstance(value, tuple):
                self._a = A(value[0], value[1])
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                # ?           
                self._a.x = value

b = B()
b.a = 1 # a.setter will be in charge
```

output:

```
a.setter acting
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but if you are looking for another approach you could inherit the `A` class and `b.a.x` becomes `b.x`.

You can achieve this by adding the following line in `B`'s constructor

`super(A, self).__init__()`

hence 
`b.a.x == b.x`