# Overriding an inherited property setter (without fset)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

This question arises from reading the answer to [Overriding an inherited property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909094/overriding-an-inherited-property-setter/31909212). Assume the case where I have the base `Person` class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value
```

Following the top-voted answer the correct way to override the setter would be:

```
class Superhero(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    @Person.name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        Person.name.fset(self, "Super " + value)
```

Would there be a difference if instead, the `Superhero` class updated the `_name` attribute directly? i.e.

```
class Superhero(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    @Person.name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = "Super " + value
```

(I know, a comment in the referenced question would have been enough but due to reputation I do not have the privileges to ask.)

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? I'd expect it to work, but now the child has to know what the backing attribute is named too.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked. I get your point, better the to stick to the fset since there is no need to know how the property is named.