# Python inherit the property of one class to another

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have three different class's and some variables in it

```
class A(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"

class B(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"

class C(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"
```

Where `a = "Hello"` and `b = "World"` is common to all class's, how can I declare these variables as a global class and Inherit the properties to these tables.

I Tried in this way, but am not able to get the solution.

```
class G(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"

class A(object, G):
    pass
```

Here I'm trying to inherit the whole property of the class. Please help me to solve this thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is wrong with what you have done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding properties in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019643/overriding-properties-in-python)

Comment: G is already an object

Comment: You could consider not using inheritance (and introducing an extra `G` class) at all but just making the two variables global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it. Please let know in comments if there is something that you don't understand, or if I am doing anything wrong.

```
class A(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

c = C()
print(c.a,c.b)
```

> Prints Hello World

Comment: Thanks @Abhijeet, I got solution from your answer, thanks a lot

Comment: No need to declare a  and b again with same values. You inherit them already! only reason to declare again if you want to store new values for each class but still you can call the parent's Class value with super()

Comment: This answer is quite misleading. This is a terrible example of how to do inheritance.

Comment: Edited the answer. Sorry for declaring variables again. This is what I intended to do but removing extra declarations slipped out of my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(object):
    a = "Hello"
    b = "World"

class B(A):
  something

class C(B):
  something

c = C()
print(c.a,c.b)
```

You don't have to re-declare a and b each time or else why would you inherit in the first place. If you declare them you basically are overwriting the parent's variable with the child's. If you do that you can call the parent's one with super().

Comment: Your example similar to Abhijeetk431 answer, its helpfull thanks.

Comment: yes but pay attention that you dont have to redeclare a and b!You welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Define class `A` as:

```
class A(G):
    pass
```

The problem with repeating the base class `object` is that it creates a base class resolution conflict, since `A` was inheriting it twice:  Once directly, and once indirectly through class `G`.