# Overriding parent class property without explicitly using the parent class' name

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator, super

There are two common approaches to calling the parent `__init__()` from a child:

1. With an **explicit** call to the Parent:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
```

2. With an **implicit** call to the Parent, using `super()`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
```

The second approach has an advantage: if instead of inheriting from Parent, you wanted to inherit from Parent2, you'd simply have to change one line. In the first approach, you'd have to to change two.

**My question is as follows: can the same reasoning be applied to decorators?**

Consider the following base class:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @value.setter:
    def value(self, value_new):
        self._value = value_new
```

If I wanted to override only the getter in a child class, I'd do the following:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.value.getter  # Explicit call to the parent class
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

**Is there a way to avoid explicitly calling the parent?** (Just like we did at the top)

**The code below doesn't work, but is there something similar that would?**

```
class Child(Parent):
    @super.value.getter   # super instead of explicit call to Parent
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Comment: Maybe you've left out some important detail here, but it looks like you could just use `@property` in the child class - you aren't actually inheriting anything from the parent.

Comment: @jasonharper I did leave out code for the sake of simplicity. You can imagine that when we override, we would do something to value before returning it. So there's a reason to actually override, not just inherit.

Comment: @FMc I do want to delegate the call to the Parent property getter while at the same time maintaining the inherited setter. If I were to fully override the getter, I'd also need to override the setter. That's why I do it as shown. My question is really about having super as a decorator to avoid explicitly calling the parent. All the rest is incidental.

Comment: @manocormen OK, I'm tracking now -- makes sense. Related, but doesn't really solve the problem, unless you control the Parent class too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019643/overriding-properties-in-python

Comment: @manocormen You could set `Child.value` outside the `Child` class definition, by using the builtin `property()` function: roughly `Child.value = property(...)`. That builtin takes params for the various functions: assign `fget` to your custom getter and the rest to the attributes of `Child.__mro__[1].value` -- which is just an indirect way to get `Parent.value`, its property. But that's a lot of work to avoid a tiny code-maintenance hassle.

Comment: @FMC It is a lot of work. I was really looking for a concise decorator equivalent of super(). It seems that there isn't one in Python, yet. I'll make due with explicit calls to the parent. The workarounds seem to introduce unnecessary complexity.