# How to properly extend a setter in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I'm looking for a way to extend the setter of a property when subclassing a python class. I looked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237432/14409478) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7019643/14409478), but the answers provided either seem to be complicated, or do not cover the case of *extending* the setter instead of *overriding* it. Since these questions are rather old, I thought maybe there was a better way to override a setter.

Looking [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in the documentation, I found out that properties have `fget`, `fset` and `fdel` attributes refering to getter, setter and deleter methods. Using that, I came up with the following solution.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        print('This is Parent\'s setter')
        self._x = new_x


class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        Parent.x.fset(self, new_x)
        print('This is Child\'s setter')


test = Child(0)
```

Running the script, I get the output

```
This is Parent's setter
This is Child's setter
```

which is exactly what I expect.

This solution seems to work, but I feel like there should be a better solution, since it seems weird to hard-code the name of the parent class in the setter of the child class, and to explicitly use `self` as an argument. Is there a better way to do that? For example, is there a way to do something similar using `super`? What is the standard way to extend a setter in a subclass?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `super`, it'd look like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        super(Child, type(self)).x.fset(self, new_x)
        print("This is Child's setter")
```

`super` implements a `__getattribute__` method, but no `__setattr__`, so we can't do `super().x = new_x`. We can use `super` to look up the parent's property object, but in the setter, that's all it can do for us.

There is very little benefit to doing things this way. It may be useful in certain multiple inheritance situations, if two subclasses want to cooperatively override the same property, but doing multiple inheritance correctly is **much** more complicated than just using `super` everywhere.

(Passing `type(self)` to `super` is almost always wrong, but that's when you're passing it as the first argument. `super(type(self), self)` breaks in the presence of grandchild classes. Passing `type(self)` as the second argument makes sense if you want to use `super` to look up a class attribute in an instance method, which is what we're doing here.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments about `super`. So my solution is acceptable? Would there be a better way to extend a setter?